# Can I Run XCode 4.3.X without OSX 10.7 Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, upgrade, xcode

I cannot upgrade my Macbook to OSX 10.7 (Lion) but would like to have XCode 4.3 as I am now running iOS 5.1 and will soon be looking at iOS 6 ... and XCode 4.2 does not allow me to work with iOS 5.1 or 6.0

I see on the developer center there is a spot to download XCode 4.2 for Snow Leopard but I do not see 4.3 for Snow Leopard.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unlikely...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377467/xcode-4-3-for-snow-leopard

Note that Xcode 4.3 is only available from the AppStore.

Comment: I will approve the answer but it doesn't mean that I like it.

Comment: Can't install XCode 4.3 but can install the iOS 5.1 SDK, which is good enough for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-is-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-use-with-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard